# Keeping a process in the foreground

Tags: shell, python, raspbian, libreoffice

My script invokes the shell to run the following command on startup:

`libreoffice --impress --norestore --show /home/directory`

This process is repeated everyday to have the presentation be displayed continuously for periods longer than a few hours. However, after a period of about ~10-20 minutes, the slideshow freezes on a slide or on the transitioning of the slide. Sometimes a simple tap of the arrow key fixes this and resumes the show but goes back to the previous state after some time as well. From what I can determine, I believe Linux is putting the process to the background or to "sleep", pausing the process. Being new to Linux, is there a command that can be invoked to have the process run uninterrupted or have the slideshow running indefinitely?

Comment: Linux doesn't do that. It doesn't terminate processes, no matter how long they run, with the notable exception of high memory pressure, and it doesn't "freeze" them. How did you determine this? I believe the problem lies in Libreoffice.

Comment: @berndbausch I assumed this because I tried ruling out every other possible factor on the Raspberry Pi. The power source and memory were good so I assumed Linux just "paused" it. I tried doing a barebone simple presentation and I achieved the same problem. I am stuck at this point trying to figure this out.